# modify save button action in sugarcrm

Tags: jquery, customization, sugarcrm

I have just created a custom module from Person class.
My issue is When I click on `Create New Link` at the right corner, the data entry page appear.
After I fill up data and click Save I want to save the data to database and make some fields blank for fill up again, How can i do with JQuery?

Comment: Can you explain your use case more?

Comment: It sounds as though you want a reusable "Create" form for batch data entry such that the "Save" button behaves like "Save and add another" without taking you to view the newly created record. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I want to reusable it like "Save and add another" without taking you to view the newly created record.

Comment: I haven't personally done this before, but I'm thinking through some possible solutions. No promises! Do you have the full "Edit View" in mind as the data entry UI, or are you thinking of the "Quick Create" view?